# how to create a scroll bar in plasm simple popup modal...?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, popup, mootools

The jquery for the popup is below

```
 $("alert").addEvent("click", function(e){
    e.stop();
    var SM = new SimpleModal({"btn_ok":"Alert button"});
        SM.show({
          "title":"Alert Modal Title",
          "contents":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."
        });
  })
```

This code shows the Popup Modal. If i increase the content in the "contents:" attribute the popup modal doesnot makes a scroll to show the content.

I need a scroll bar to view the content below.

Comment: The size should increase automatically to accommodate the content. And, I think there is an error in your syntax, `$( 'alert' )` should either be `$( '.alert' )` or `$( '#alert' )`

Comment: when i use `$( '.alert' )` or `$( '#alert' )` the popup doesnot works.

Comment: That is interesting...

Comment: is ther aany other solution...?

Comment: What about jQuery UI, or any other UI frameworks perhaps